# Wordpress- Uploaded image in 'Media Library' not displaying (insecure content Issue)

Tags: php, image, wordpress, blogs, media-library

I encountered an error while debugging it in developer tab:

```
The page at ‘https://...' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from ‘http://..../files/2013/12/Penguins-150x150.jpg': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Do you think we need to change the URL/permalink of the picture and changed it to “HTTPS” during adding new pictures in “Media Library (media-new.php)”?

Do you have any idea where to get started? Let me know your thoughts on this..

please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should leave out the protocol name from the url so it looks something like:

//domain.com/myimage.jpg

This will load the image over te protocol that is currently used for that page.

Comment: I really wanna try this but I'm new to wordpress and I don't know where should I set this, or which php file should I modify.

Comment: Have a look here http://www.sitepoint.com/crimes-against-wordpress and start reading from the header *Failing to Support HTTPS*

Comment: I think that what @Bart is trying to tell you is that if you do not know what he is talking about , then most likely it is one of your plugins / themes to blame ..